# XSLT - Copy all other nodes, add 1 new node

Tags: xml, xslt

I have created an XSLT and i was wondering how it is possible to copy all nodes between one set of tags, and add another tag at the bottom. I have created the XSLT that has all the logic for determining which tag to add, and what it should be called. However the issue i am now getting is that i can not copy all the other tags across too. Below are the files in question:

**XSLT**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    version="1.0">
    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

    <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="/csvImportSchema">
        <csvImportSchema>
            <xsl:for-each select="payload">
                <payload>
                    <xsl:copy-of select="@*"/>
                    <xsl:variable name="ean">
                        <xsl:value-of select="ean"/>
                    </xsl:variable>
                    <xsl:for-each select="../product">
                        <xsl:if test="ean = $ean">
                            <productId><xsl:value-of select="article"/></productId>
                        </xsl:if>
                    </xsl:for-each>
                </payload>
            </xsl:for-each>
        </csvImportSchema>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**INPUT**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<csvImportSchema>
    <payload>
        <test>1</test>
        <test2>2</test2>
        <test3>3</test3>
        <ean>1111111111</ean>
        <productId/>
    </payload>
    <product>
        <article>722619</article>
        <ean>1111111111</ean>
    </product>
</csvImportSchema>
```

**CURRENT OUTPUT**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<csvImportSchema>
    <payload>
        <productId>722619</productId>
    </payload>
</csvImportSchema>
```

**DESIRED OUTPUT**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<csvImportSchema>
    <payload>
        <test>1</test>
        <test2>2</test2>
        <test3>3</test3>
        <ean>1111111111</ean>
        <productId>722619</productId>
    </payload>
</csvImportSchema>
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

**This short and simple transformation**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
 <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

 <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
     <xsl:copy>
       <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
     </xsl:copy>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="productId">
  <productId>
    <xsl:value-of select="../../product/article"/>
  </productId>
 </xsl:template>
 <xsl:template match="product"/>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**when applied on the provided XML document:**

```
<csvImportSchema>
    <payload>
        <test>1</test>
        <test2>2</test2>
        <test3>3</test3>
        <ean>1111111111</ean>
        <productId/>
    </payload>
    <product>
        <article>722619</article>
        <ean>1111111111</ean>
    </product>
</csvImportSchema>
```

**produces the wanted, correct result**:

```
<csvImportSchema>
   <payload>
      <test>1</test>
      <test2>2</test2>
      <test3>3</test3>
      <ean>1111111111</ean>
      <productId>722619</productId>
   </payload>
</csvImportSchema>
```

**Explanation**:

1. The **[identity rule](http://dpawson.co.uk/xsl/sect2/identity.html)** copies "as-is" every node for which it is selected for execution.
2. An overriding template matching `product` "deletes" this element from the output (by its empty body).
3. Another overriding template matches `productId` and generates this element with a text-node child taken from `product/article`.

Answer (score 2):

One observation on your code. Don't use this:

```
<xsl:variable name="ean">
    <xsl:value-of select="../ean"/>
</xsl:variable>
```

when you could write this:

```
<xsl:variable name="ean" select="../ean"/>
```

Not only is it verbose, it's also incredibly inefficient: instead of binding $ean to an existing node, you are extracting the string value of an existing node, forming a text node with that string value, creating a new XML document tree, and adding this text node to the content of this new document. (I once got a stylesheet to run 3 times faster by eliminating this horrible construct.)

Answer (score 1):

It should be as simple as changing your payload `xsl:copy-of select="@*"/` to

```
<xsl:copy-of select="*[local-name() != 'productId'] | @*"/>
```

i.e. copy everything, except `productId`, because you build this up manually.

This gives the output you've required

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<csvImportSchema>
  <payload>
    <test>1</test>
    <test2>2</test2>
    <test3>3</test3>
    <ean>1111111111</ean>
    <productId>722619</productId>
  </payload>
</csvImportSchema>
```

Answer (score 1):

This XSLT should do the job and uses way more COPY tags and templates. Maybe don't do everything in one xsl:template (my opinion).

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    version="1.0">
    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

    <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="/csvImportSchema">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="*"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="csvImportSchema/payload/productId">
        <xsl:variable name="ean">
            <xsl:value-of select="../ean"/>
        </xsl:variable>
        <xsl:for-each select="../../product">
            <xsl:if test="ean = $ean">
                <productId><xsl:value-of select="article"/></productId>
            </xsl:if>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="csvImportSchema/product">
        <!-- do not copy -->
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="csvImportSchema/payload">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>   
</xsl:stylesheet>
```